# How to call parent method of multiple nested inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I want to call A.f() from B.f(), but both are inner classes, if I write the traditional way, it does not compiles.
Any easy way without a temporary variable like the `A _this` in the code?

```
class MyClass {
  [...]
  class A {
    public void f(){System.out.println("A.f");};
    public void g(){System.out.println("A.g");};
  }
  class B {
    public void f(){System.out.println("B.f");};
  }

  public A a() {
    return new A() {
      public void g() {
        // I want to avoid this step
        final A _this = this;
        new B() {
          public void f() {
            System.out.println("foo");
            // this works
            _this.f();
            // but this does not compile
            A.this.f();
          }
        }.f();
      }
    };
  }
  [...]
}
```

Comment: you have conceptual errors in the code. there are multiple ways to fix i. which solution to choose, depends on the actual real world code. as this looks like a simplified example of a real world problem, it is hard to say how you would have to fix it.
if this WAS your actual code, you would make all the f and g methods static, and then you can call `A.f();`

Comment: @sol4me `// but this does not compiles`. The OP knows that.

Comment: @BackSlash The code  `public A a() {...}`is not surrounded in any brackets, If OP put the code properly in curly brackets then everything compiles fine and works. I was not refering to `//but this does not compiles`

Comment: @sol4me I just omitted the entire main class because that code was not relevant, edited the code so as you know the context.

Comment: @hoijui I don't have conceptual errors, I only ask for a way to call the method with the same name, note that if the method in A had a different name like h() it was not a problem. Those classes are 3party classes so I cannot change names nor make them static

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the code in brackets properly and then `A.this.f()` compiles fine E.g.

```
class A {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("A.f");
    }

    public void g() {
        System.out.println("A.g");
    }

    public A a() {
        return new A() {
            public void g() {
                =
                new B() {
                    public void f() {
                        System.out.println("foo");
                        A.this.f();
                    }
                }.f();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().a().g();
    }
}

class B {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("B.f");
    }

}
```

Updated : You can replace `_this.f();` with `new MyClass().new A().f();` but it will result in creation of new Object.

Comment: A and B are 3party classes, I cannot change the API.

Comment: @user3752469 `A.this.f();` will not work because `A` is not enclosing class. The current solution which you have `  final A _this = this;` is the  way to access A in nested class `B`

Comment: I dont want to modify classes `A` and `B` they are actually part of an external API. I want the solution in the `a()` method of `MyClass`

Comment: @user3752469 So you can replace inside `a()` method of my class `_this.f();` with `new MyClass().new A().f()`

Comment: It does not work because the new created `A` class does not have the overriden `A.g()` method in the inner class, it is used in the original API `A.f()` method